# Pantheon terminal error message

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I'm getting this error message everytime I start the terminal:

```
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: PROMPT_COMMAND: line 1: `dbus-send --type=method_call --session --dest=net.launchpad.pantheon-terminal /net/launchpad/pantheon_terminal org.pantheon.terminal.ProcessFinished string:$PANTHEON_TERMINAL_ID string:"$(history 1 | cut -c 8-)" >/dev/null 2>&1; ; printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"'
```

Comment: Can you post your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` so that we can see where it could have gone wrong?

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as **Answer** that helped solving your problem. If you have solved this on your own, please write it down as answer and mark it so.